# Red-Black Tree Assignment vs Splicing

Tags: java, red-black-tree

Why does the method remove(x) in the RedBlackTree implementation perform the assignment u.parent = w.parent? Shouldn’t this already be done by the call to splice(w)?

This is the code for remove(x):

[image]

No new code was provided in the RedBlackTree section for splice(), so I'm assuming it's the same as the 
[code for splice() for Binary Search Trees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cjHn.png)

Comment: where's the code for splice?

Comment: It looks like `splice` is mostly a placeholder for any cleanup operations one might want to perform. Omitting the call to `splice` would leave a valid tree. The dangling `w.parent` pointer should be dealt with, I guess. Seeing the call to `splice` would help.

Comment: Thanks for your input!
What's confusing is that no code for splice is provided - this is all the information I can find about splice. "Just
like the remove(x) operation in a BinarySearchTree, this operation (remove(x) operation in a Red-Black Tree) boils
down to finding a node w with only one child, u, and splicing w out of the
tree by having w.parent adopt u"

Comment: just added a method for splice() under the assumption that it's the same as Binary Search Tree's!

Comment: what was the answer?